# Using UITableView to show on-board pdfs

Tags: ios, uitableview, variables

I'm trying to set up a table view for the user to choose from a series of on-board pdfs to be displayed in a `UIWebView`. I have this for displaying the pdfs:

```
NSString *urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"pdf"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[biblioView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Which works fine. What I can't work out is how to use the result of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in the table to load the selected pdf called 1 thru x into the `UIWebView`.

Suspect it's setting up a variable, loading the result into it and then somehow deploying that in the pdf code above, but I just can't get it.

I'm sure the obvious answer to this question is "learn some basic coding, doofus", but I'm doing this as a favour, in a hurry and from a standing start, so any hints/tips/snippets would be VERY gratefully received. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You need a `UITableViewController` to display the PDF list, checkout some Apple example e.g. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318 to get started, what you need to understand is to implement `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`.

Then you need a `UIViewController` which contains an `UIWebView`, load PDF as your code. You can setup a property to get the different PDF source from the `UITableViewDelegate`'s `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Excellent - I understand some of that :-) I'll give it a go - many thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above answer..

Your `UITableView` will be back by some data structure, possibly static in your case. You override the the `UITableViewDatasource` method `cellForRowAtIndexPath....` to to tell the table view what to display in each cell (it's called once for each cell in sequence). You would usually be using the `indexPath.Row` parameter to query your data structure (eg an array index).

When a user selects a table view cell, your overridden `UITableViewController` implementation (subclass) method

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath`

will be called. You can use the index selected to re-query the data structure to determine which pdf the user selected.

It's then just a case of dynamically building your url address.